# MySQL database name with hyphen

Tags: mysql5.1

I have recently upgraded my staging database server from MySQL 5.0.84 to 5.1.72. I am trying to restore the mysqldump after upgrade. The database name in the dump is `gss-app`. But the database folder name under `/var/lib/mysql` turned to be `gss@022dapp`, but when I login to mysql using `mysql -u root -p` and type `show databases;` it lists the database name as `gss-app` only and I can `Use Database gss-app` and list the tables using `show tables` command.

The restore was failed with an error `Got a packet bigger than --max_allowed_packet size`. That time the database was partially restored and I took that chance to rename the `gss@022dapp` folder to `gss-app` and logged into mysql shell.

It listed the database name as `@mysql@gss-app` and I was not able to get into the database. Now I'm running the database restore once again with `--max_allowed_packet_size=1024M` and I see the `gss@022dapp` folder was created in `/var/lib/mysql`.

Should I concern about the folder name in `/var/lib/mysql`? Or can I use a different database name while restoring?

Answer (score 1):

Specifically to your question about using a different name while restoring: with mysqldump you can either do `mysqldump databasename` or `mysqldump --databases databasename`. The former doesn't put a `create db` statement in it, the latter does.

When you have made the dump with the former statement, you can just manually create a new db and load the dump with something like `mysql newdbname < dump.sql`. In case of the latter, you can just open your dump file and change the name.

A sidenote, I think it's bad design on MySQL's `mysqldump` part to have this difference, BTW. If you backup without the `--databases` statement, you have to make a database first before you can restore. And that database might have a different charset or collation than what the database originally had. In my opinion, if you dump a database, it should contain all data and metadata. Same goes for having to supply `--routines` and `--events`. I can imagine options like `--no-routines` can be handy, but by default *not* dumping routines? Hmm.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did not use `--databases` option when taking mysqldump. As of now, I am just using the database with the same name, I will soon upgrade 5.1 to 5.5 after all the testing done. I will use this method when I take a dump of 5.1 before upgrading. Thanks again!